# Error installing Windows SDK 10.0.14393

Tags: windows, sdk, failed-installation

installation of VS 2015 Update 3 reported an error installing Windows SDK 10.0.14393.

i found some forum entries about that issue, tipping for separat installation of the SDK. i did so. result:

> Blockquote
>   Installation did not complete successfully.

Log-File shows that the rollback started after

CAQuietExec:  Creating UnionWinMD using mdmerge tool
CAQuietExec:  MDMerge failed. Please check See MDMerge tool logs at C:\Users\Lothar\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\Logs\27555-MDMerge.log and C:\Users\Lothar\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\Logs\27555-MDMerge.err
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction GenUnionWinMD returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (74:50) [11:34:03:800]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035

Any suggestions?

Comment: forgot to mention: Windows 10 SDK 10.0.10586.212 installation works

Comment: If anyone encounters this on 10.0.10586.212 see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849284/1269722

Answer (score 0):

My instance of your problem included problems with the KB3165756 Update to Visual Studio 2015, lo these last 2 days.  Though I've cleared that (downloaded the VS2015 .iso AND ran it OFFLINE <-- that was key), the 10.0.14393 Windows SDK installer now simply terminates without doing anything.  Like you, the 10586 SDK installer went in smoothly.

Comment: Installation with the .iso did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the version 10.0.14393.33 this helped me: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2571#issuecomment-259671943

You have to download the entire installer package via web-install of SDK. Then go to the folder with downloaded data and edit UserExperienceManifest.xml the described way.

Comment: Just checked: this solves for 10.0.14393.795 too.

If anyone wonders why I need so ancient version of Win10 SDK: at the moment cmake (3.9.5) works correctly only with that version (I use alos VS2015 up3)