# Failed to install Windows 10 SDK v10.0.10586 for Visual studio 2015 professional, Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sdk, windows-7-x64

I uninstalled visual studio 2015 because I was trying to fix another issue I was having, and it was suggested an uninstall/install might fix it.

1) I went through programs and features, found VS2015, selected change, then uninstalled VS2015.

2) rebooted

3) I tried the install again, making sure windows SDK 10.0.10586 was selected and I received this message after the install completed:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlGP.png)

The log has these error messages:
[2094:210C][2018-08-15T12:07:34]i000: MUX:  Updating secondary installer progress display name: Outer=Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586), Inner=
[2080:2084][2018-08-15T12:08:42]e000: Error 0x80048646: Process returned error: 0x80048646
[2080:2084][2018-08-15T12:08:42]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2094:2098][2018-08-15T12:08:42]e000: Error 0x80048646: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.

4) rebooted

5) I tried a repair and then modify, I get the same message.

6) rebooted

I did not readily find a solution online, but I did find a suggestion to try downloading it from Windows SDK archive: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

7) After trying to run the install or the download, I get this:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pu8VA.png) I am certainly connected to the internet. So then I dig more into the error message, and I came across this guide: https://codedocu.com/Details?d=1588&a=9&f=54&l=0&v=d

It suggests clearing the package cache before modifying the install to add windows SDK. This is where things get weird...

8) I clear my package cache, then go back to programs and features, and VS2015 is GONE. However, the shortcut on my desktop still works, VS2015 executes, no problem, but I can't modify the install.

9) rebooted

10) Re-install VS2015 so it would show on the programs and features list again. 
It still failed to install the SDK, but I wasnt expecting it to work that time.

11) rebooted

12) I tried a complete wipe of VS2015 because I know the uninstall doesn't really get rid of everything. There is a great tool for that here: https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases I ran the uninstaller, confirmed that it worked.

13) rebooted

14) Ran the installer again ( with windows SDK selected), and I get the same error message after the install completed:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exlGP.png). I don't know what else to try, if anyone has a suggestion, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear if among all your attempts you ever reboot the machine. (You should do it always after a seuup failure before trying something else) 

Please can you edit the issue to be more detailed, i.e. 
1) Uninstalling VS2015 from control panel
...
3) Wiped VS2015 by using the tool 
4) Reboot the computer
5) ...

Comment: 15605 = ERROR_INSTALL_NETWORK_FAILURE. Check your Internet connection or download the [ISO](https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/1/01111605-8CDF-4A88-BB06-C20E97E8B3D5/iso_windowssdk/15063.468.170612-1856.rs2_release_svc_sec_WindowsSDK.iso) from a 2nd PC

Comment: @magicandre1981, the ISO you posted is for SDK 10.0.15063, I need 10.0.10586, could you post that?

Comment: ok, I've [build my own ISO for that 10586 version](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5sbct1ckvbw55m/WinSDK_10586.iso?dl=1) because MSFT doesn't provide an iso for that build.

Comment: You are right, I searched long and hard with no trace of such ISO. BUT THIS WORKED!!! Thank you so much magicandre1981, I am able to compile my code once again. You are a life saver, much love <3

Answer (score 3):

(Not directly related to the Question, but) If anyone wants to cleanup their installed SDKs (like I did) and runs into the problem where neither installing nor uninstalling Windows SDK `10.0.10586` works and has the following in their install log:

```
CAQuietExec:  Creating UnionWinMD using mdmerge tool
CAQuietExec:  MDMerge failed. Please check See MDMerge tool logs at C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\Logs\10498-MDMerge.log and C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\Logs\10498-MDMerge.err
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: Command line returned an error.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: CAQuietExec Failed
```

And in the referenced log

```
Processing input metadata file C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\17728\WinMDs\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd.
```

And in the error log

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
MDMERGE : error MDM2018: The type "Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IPrintTaskSettingsActivatedEventArgs" defined in file C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\UnionWinmdWorkingFolder\17728\WinMDs\Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivatedEventsContract.winmd was referenced but could not be found.
```

I assume this is because it tries to execute a custom action which is meant to be running on installation. To get rid of it you can edit (and backup) `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\GenerateUnionWinMD.cmd` to be an empty batch file (I just left a single `echo`). The uninstallation worked afterwards and the SDK is gone.
I suggest uninstalling ALL SDKs and installing the ones you need afterwards just to be safe.

I post this here as it was the page I landed on when trying to find anyone running into this...

Answer (score 1):

Since MSFT no longer provides an ISO for this build, magicandre1981 built his own and uploaded it (see comments). That install ran fine and I can compile again!